# Automatic List in html with Mustache JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

Im trying to render a simple unordered list with mustache.

This is my code:

```
var num = 0;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var template = '<ul><li>{{name}}</li></ul>'; 
    var data = {name: 'nome' + num}

    while (num < 6) 
    {
        num++;                      
        data = {name: 'nome' + num};            

    }
```

The output is:

- nome6

But i am trying to create automatic with the conditional:

- nome1

- nome2

- nome3

- nome4

- nome5

- nome6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is not an array, if you want to print something in a loop you need to create an array in your js and pass it on the template.

View:

```
{
    "beatles": [
        { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Lennon" },
        { "firstName": "Paul", "lastName": "McCartney" },
        { "firstName": "George", "lastName": "Harrison" },
        { "firstName": "Ringo", "lastName": "Starr" }
    ],
    "name": function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
    {{#beatles}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/beatles}}
</ul>
```